# JQuery / PHP Dropdown Variable For TextArea Value

Tags: php, jquery

I have a functioning "Account Notes" page that allows the user to add notes to their account for their own uses.  I want to allow my admins to input notes into user accounts without logging in.  I have a Dropdown on the Admin page that allows the admins to select a user.  After selecting the user I want to echo the notes already in their notes section into the TextArea below and allow an update to the notes.

```
function getNotes(){
    global $id;
    $result = query("SELECT * FROM `extras` WHERE `userid`=".$id);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        return $row['notes'];
    }
}

<form action="update.php" method="post">
    <h4 class="widgettitle title-primary">Account Notes</h4>
    <br/>

      <textarea rows="20" scroll="auto" class="txt" name="notes" style="width: 80%;"/><?=getNotes();?></textarea>
    <div style="text-align:center;"><button class="btn btn-primary">Update</button></div>
      <input type="hidden" name="formtype" value="updatenotes" />
      <input type="hidden" name="redir" value="notes.php" />

    </form>

    </form>

    </div>

            </div><!--row-fluid-->
```

All of the above code works correctly, so there are no issues above.  My issue lies below...

The following code is what I have on my admin.php page for the user notes addition code...

```
    <div id="addusernotes">
<form action="update.php" method="post">
        <h4 class="widgettitle title-primary"><center>Add User Notes</center></h4><br/>

    <?php
            echo '<select id="user" name="user">';
                $user = query("SELECT * FROM `users` ORDER by `user`");
                if($user && mysql_num_rows($user)) 
{
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($user))
    {
                echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['user'].'</option>';
    }
}
                echo '</select>';
        ?><br/>

        Notes:<br/>
    <textarea rows="5" scroll="auto" class="txt" name="adminusernotes" style="width: 80%;"/></textarea><br/>  

        <input type="submit" name="adminnotes" value="Add Notes"><br/><br/>
        <input type="hidden" name="formtype" value="adminusernotes" />
        <input type="hidden" name="redir" value="admin.php" />
</form>
```

What JQuery do I need to add to the admin.php file to allow the Notes from the DB to display in the TextArea?  I have been stumped on this for nearly 3 days.....Any help will be more than appreciated!!!

FYI....I have intentionally left out some of my "proprietary code for security reasons...

Comment: So... where's your jQuery that you've tried to do? I don't see any jQuery/JS code anywhere.

Comment: I tried something like this:  

$("#user").change(function () {
        var userSel = this.value;
        var user = $('#user').val();
    });

I am lacking in my JQuery skills.....Thus, my reason for asking for help

Comment: @BradJackson, your question and comments do not make sense. It is obvious that you are a beginner and you are still confused about everything. That is normal, however, may I suggest to you to read a few books, watch a few tutorials on youtube, as of currently you are not able to understand any answers because of your lack of knowledge. And it is also challenging to answer a confused question.

Comment: I appreciate your "no nonsense" approach, however, the "lack of knowledge" you so brilliantly noticed, is the reason I posted my issue on here.  I'm more than able when it comes to coding in PHP, however, I am not proficient at JQuery.  If someone would take the time to actually help, instead of hechtle, I may be able to learn something new.....Thank you either way for your input.....

Comment: In contrast with you I am not being sarcastic, I just noticed that you are not ready for the information and I have suggested that you should start with tutorials. 1-2 hours on youtube watching Douglas Crockford's videos and you will know a LOT about Javascript compared to your current knowledge. Then, browsing jquery's documentation for 2-3 hours would enable you to understand its syntax. Then, looking at a few tutorials about server and client-side interaction would enable you to start your work. Unfortunately, instead of doing that you are wasting your energy making sarcastic comments.

Answer (score 0):

To alter a textarea's content with jQuery, you simply use:

```
$("#element-id-here").val("whatever value...");
```

But give your textarea an ID first. And you can change the value to a variable too.

If you want PHP to echo the textarea contents:

```
<textarea><?php echo "contents here"; ?></textarea>
```

Comment: You said you wanted jQuery to change the value of a textarea. What has the select got to do with it?

Comment: The select is a list of all users.  The value of the select is the user id within the DB.  I need to display the user notes based upon the user id....

Comment: In that case you need to look into JSON which can grab a user's notes based on the option you've selected.

Comment: I would like to stay away from using JSON for a simple SQL query.  I was able to make this process work with the logged in Session User through PHP, however, I am unable to change the userid variable on the fly to allow the notes to update within the textarea and then be able to update them.....

Comment: If you want to get data when you change a field, you need to either define everything when the page loads, or use JSON. Otherwise you need to reload the page using $_GET.